# How do I always show a widget independent from the design package in Magento?

Tags: magento, widget

In other words, I want to show a widget in all catalog pages of all design packages. I have diferent design packages for many categories, but I have a widget for show ads in catalog pages. In default theme shows the widget ok, but in the categories that theme changes the widget don’t shows. By default when create a widget it’s necesary specify a design package, it’s posible to bypass that requirement? I’m using magento professional. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Inject it with observer to layout